# You can definitely never predict what will happen

Tags: adverbs

I found an example in Cambridge Dictionary(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position):

You can definitely never predict what will happen.

In the above example, what is the adverb "definitely" modifying?

a) You can [[**definitely never**] predict] what will happen. ('definitely' modifying 'never') ***Or***

b) You can [never [**predict definitely**]] what will happen. ('definitely' modifying 'predict')

Can I write the original sentence the same way as **b)**?

Comment: It modifies "never predict what will happen".

Comment: A paraphrase is 'It is certain that you can never predict what will happen'. 'Definitely' is a modal sentential adverb (in the traditional analysis), 'modifying' the statement (adding a value judgement, the speaker's assessment of the absolute truth of the statement). The adverb 'modifies' 'You can never predict what will happen'.

Comment: Your b) has a different meaning than the original. In b), *definitely* modifies *predict* and means *You can never predict with certainty what will happen.* The original modifies *never predict* and means *You can truly never predict what will happen.*